# Sticky Menu Glitch

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to resolve an issue with a "sticky" horizontal menu.

It technically works, in that the menu's position is fixed while the pages scrolls up and down.

The issue at the moment is that then the page is scrolled back up to the original position, the new resting place of the objects below the sticky menu return to the top of the browser, behind the sticky menu at the top.

Website link here - http://thebicycleshop-online.co.uk/

```js
 <script>
        // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
        window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

        // Get the navbar
        var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

        // Get the offset position of the navbar
        var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

        // Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
        function myFunction() {
            if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
            navbar.classList.add("sticky")
            } 
            else {
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        }
    
        $('.menu').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('check');
        });
    
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
        });
        }
    </script>
```

```css
                  /*---HAMBURGER---*/

@charset "utf-8";

* {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}

div.menu{
    width: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

div.menu ul.hamburger{
    list-style: none;
}

div.menu ul.hamburger li{
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    background: Black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    transition: all 300ms;
}

div.menu.check ul.hamburger li.top{
    transform: rotate(-140deg) translateY(-13px);
    margin-left: 7px;
}

div.menu.check ul.hamburger li.middle{
    opacity: 0;
}

div.menu.check ul.hamburger li.bottom{
    transform: rotate(140deg) translateY(13px);
    margin-left: 7px;
}

                 /*---STICKY MENU---*/

/* Style the navbar */
#navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: White;
}

/* Navbar links */
#navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Page content */
.content {
    padding: 16px;
}

/* The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the navigation bar gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

                    /*---TITLE---*/

.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 45px;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    margin: 14px;
}

              /*---NAVIGATION LINKS---*/

/* A link that has not been visited */
a:link {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* A link that has been visited */
a:visited {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* A link that is hovered on */
a:hover {
    color: #f1ac02;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/* A link that is selected */
a:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

             /*---NEW WORK CONDUCTED---*/

#section1 {
    background-color: white;
    width: 0 auto;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#section2 {
    background-color: white;
    width: 0 auto;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>TESTING</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"> 
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="Test2_main_new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
body{
    position: relative;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="font-family: helvetica; margin: auto; height: 4060px; width: 100%; background-color: dimgrey;">
    <div id="navbar">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class="hamburger">
                <li class="top"></li>
                <li class="middle"></li>
                <li class="bottom"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="title.jpg" class="responsive" alt="#">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="section1">
        <a>Section 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
        <a>Section 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for the record, `sticky` class is never removed here

Comment: After a closer look, your code has multiple problems. For example, the sticky class is never removed, as @GrafiCode noted. If you are working from a tutorial, then you might ensure that you've followed the directions and copied the code and markup correctly. You may also want to have a look at [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/#placement) which can do much of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to add a function to monitor the scroll, just position the navbar as fixed and add padding to the first sibling after the navbar element. See below

```js
//None of this is needed for the scroll.

// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
//window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

// Get the navbar
// var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

// // Get the offset position of the navbar
// var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// // Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
// function myFunction() {
//   if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
//     navbar.classList.add("sticky")
//   }
//   else {
//     navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
//   }
// }

$('.menu').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('check');
});

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div.menu {
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

div.menu ul.hamburger {
  list-style: none;
}

div.menu ul.hamburger li {
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  background: Black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

div.menu.check ul.hamburger li.top {
  transform: rotate(-140deg) translateY(-13px);
  margin-left: 7px;
}

div.menu.check ul.hamburger li.middle {
  opacity: 0;
}

div.menu.check ul.hamburger li.bottom {
  transform: rotate(140deg) translateY(13px);
  margin-left: 7px;
}


/*---STICKY MENU---*/


/* Style the navbar */

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  /* position this to the viewport */
  top: 0;
  /* ensure it's at the top of the viewport */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: White;
}

#navbar+div {
  margin-top: 65px;
  /* set the first div to have a top margin of 65px so that when you reach the top of the scroll, the first element is still just below the navbar */
}


/* Navbar links */

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Page content */

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}


/*---TITLE---*/

.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 45px;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  margin: 14px;
}


/*---NAVIGATION LINKS---*/


/* A link that has not been visited */

a:link {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* A link that has been visited */

a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* A link that is hovered on */

a:hover {
  color: #f1ac02;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* A link that is selected */

a:active {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*---NEW WORK CONDUCTED---*/

#section1 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#section2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container' style="font-family: helvetica; margin: auto; height: 4060px; width: 100%; background-color: dimgrey;">
  <div id="navbar">
    <div class="menu">
      <ul class="hamburger">
        <li class="top"></li>
        <li class="middle"></li>
        <li class="bottom"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="title.jpg" class="responsive" alt="#">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section1">
    <a>Section 1</a>
  </div>
  <div id="section2">
    <a>Section 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: #navbar+div {
  margin-top: 65px;
  /* set the first div to have a top margin of 65px so that when you reach the top of the scroll, the first element is still just below the navbar */
}

Comment: When I add a bigger margin, the bar gets bigger, not "Section 1" gap?

Comment: Bye the way, thank you to all who answered so quickly. Much appreciated.